# jQuery Slider calling another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a bit of a newbie with jQuery sliders, so please bear with me!

I want to call my `updateData(input)` function with different input depending on the slider value, but have found that when I use if statement, it only allows one condition:

```
<div id="slider"></div>

<script>
$('#slider').slider({
    orientation: 'horizontal',
    step: 5,
    value: 0,
    animate: true,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.value > 50){
            updateData("data/commodities3.json")
        }
        else if(ui.value > 75){
            updateData("data/commodities2.json")
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Any advice on how to accomplish this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is all about how you define your conditions. Obviously, if you catch everything that is above 50 first, then it won't go through the trouble of checking the else condition.

Checking against the biggest number first would solve this issue :

```
if (ui.value > 75) {
    updateData("data/commodities2.json")
} else if (ui.value > 50) {
    updateData("data/commodities3.json")
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I just tried this, but the slider still won't move after satisfying the first condition it comes to.

Comment: Your problem is that the slider doesn't move or the function updateData doesn't execute?

Comment: The updateData executes but then the slider won't move afterwards.

Comment: Could you edit your question with the code inside of the updateData function? Perhaps it affects the behavior of the slider in some way.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, I think you need to reformat your if statements.

As you currently have it, the else if statement will never be executed because any value > 75 is also > 50.

I think you want something like this:

```
if (ui.value > 75) { DO SOMETHING }
else if (ui.value > 50) { DO SOMETHING ELSE }
```

Comment: This could work, but I am potentially going to have around 10 different inputs. So above 10, 20 etc.

Comment: If you have more values to check, use cascading statements (see my edit above). Just make sure to start with the higher values and cascade down to the lower values.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this, but it still won't move after it has reached the first condition it has satisfied.

Comment: @TomWhitaker I think you want to call the slider.slider( "value", VALUE); method inside of your updateData function?

Comment: Hi @mtaube, the updateData() function is written in D3, which may make it problematic to call the slider. I was wondering when I asked this question if perhaps there was some sort of parameter that had to be reset once the function had been called to allow the slider to move again..

Answer (score 0):

@mtaube, @joelrobichaud, thanks for your help, I managed to figure it out using a combination of your answers!

```
<slidertitle>Pages</slidertitle>
      <div id="slider"></div>


    <script>
    $('#slider').slider({
      orientation: 'horizontal',
      step: 5,
      value: 0,
      animate: false,
      change: function(event, ui) {
       if (ui.value > 75) {
        updateData("data/commodities3.json")
        }
          else if(ui.value > 50){
           updateData("data/commodities2.json")   
          }

      }
    });


    </script>
```